# How to determine if a vector is in an affine space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So the question is, how to show if a vector is in an affine space. For a regular vector space it's easy, while all i have to do is to show if a vector is a linear combination of a span. But I am strugling a bit with an affine space. So let's say I have a vector **x** and an affine space defined like **S = v + U**.  Is it okay to just subtract the vector **v** from **x** and then just chcek wether the result in in **U**?

**x - v = a** and then
**a ∈ U?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just check that $x-v$ is in $U$. $v$ is fixed so this is an easy reduction to the standard linear case.